# calculating precise (ms resolution) system timestamps for picamera frames

Tags: raspberry-pi, picamera

I'm trying to calculate timestamps for `picamera` relative to the system clock in as precise a way as possible but it's not clear to me from the documentation how this can be done.

I can set the [clock_mode](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/api_camera.html#picamera.PiCamera.clock_mode) to `"raw"` and get times relative to camera initialization time but I don't see a method to query the initialization time or I can use `"reset"` to get timestamps relative to the recording start but likewise I don't see a good way of getting a precise (ms resolution) timestamp for when recording started. I am guessing there is too much latency between my call to `camera.start_recording(...)` and the actual start of recording to use the system time before this call as the recording start time.